# Does messages.getMessages method from Telegram API support telegram channels too?

Tags: android, telegram

I want to get messages from a particular channel in Telegram using its API. I know that `messages.getMessages` is for fetching messages in a chat. But can I use this function to do what I mentioned?
In other words, How can I get messages from a Telegram channel?

Answer (score 3):

you must use layer 40 (or above) of the api in order to use channels. This layer has an specific method to fetch messages from channels

> channels.getMessages#93d7b347 channel:InputChannel id:Vector = messages.Messages;

I haven't tested old `messages.getMessages` method, but I guess it won't work for channels.

Hope this helps.

Comment: please can you share a link to the Latest Telegram Layer Info. I can't see Layer 40 on their API site.

Comment: This method takes the input channel and then a list of message ids and it populates the message ids with the full contents.

What if you only have the channel id. How do you get the message ids?

Answer (score 2):

To work around the channels you should use channel methods. A list of channel methods are available here : https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl

```
channels.getDialogs#a9d3d249 offset:int limit:int = messages.Dialogs;
channels.getImportantHistory#ddb929cb channel:InputChannel offset_id:int add_offset:int limit:int max_id:int min_id:int = messages.Messages;
channels.readHistory#cc104937 channel:InputChannel max_id:int = Bool;
channels.deleteMessages#84c1fd4e channel:InputChannel id:Vector<int> = messages.AffectedMessages;
channels.deleteUserHistory#d10dd71b channel:InputChannel user_id:InputUser = messages.AffectedHistory;
channels.reportSpam#fe087810 channel:InputChannel user_id:InputUser id:Vector<int> = Bool;
channels.getMessages#93d7b347 channel:InputChannel id:Vector<int> = messages.Messages;
channels.getParticipants#24d98f92 channel:InputChannel filter:ChannelParticipantsFilter offset:int limit:int = channels.ChannelParticipants;
channels.getParticipant#546dd7a6 channel:InputChannel user_id:InputUser = channels.ChannelParticipant;
channels.getChannels#a7f6bbb id:Vector<InputChannel> = messages.Chats;
channels.getFullChannel#8736a09 channel:InputChannel = messages.ChatFull;
channels.createChannel#f4893d7f flags:# broadcast:flags.0?true megagroup:flags.1?true title:string about:string = Updates;
channels.editAbout#13e27f1e channel:InputChannel about:string = Bool;
channels.editAdmin#eb7611d0 channel:InputChannel user_id:InputUser role:ChannelParticipantRole = Updates;
channels.editTitle#566decd0 channel:InputChannel title:string = Updates;
channels.editPhoto#f12e57c9 channel:InputChannel photo:InputChatPhoto = Updates;
channels.toggleComments#aaa29e88 channel:InputChannel enabled:Bool = Updates;
channels.checkUsername#10e6bd2c channel:InputChannel username:string = Bool;
channels.updateUsername#3514b3de channel:InputChannel username:string = Bool;
channels.joinChannel#24b524c5 channel:InputChannel = Updates;
channels.leaveChannel#f836aa95 channel:InputChannel = Updates;
channels.inviteToChannel#199f3a6c channel:InputChannel users:Vector<InputUser> = Updates;
channels.kickFromChannel#a672de14 channel:InputChannel user_id:InputUser kicked:Bool = Updates;
channels.exportInvite#c7560885 channel:InputChannel = ExportedChatInvite;
channels.deleteChannel#c0111fe3 channel:InputChannel = Updates;
```

Comment: the link is not valid anymore

Comment: I think this Link can help https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-channelssupergroupsgeogroups